# Python: How does regex re.compile(r'^[-\w]+$') search? Or, how does regex work in this context?

Tags: python, regex

By reading the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match) it seems to me that

```
re.compile(r'^[-\w]+$')
```

would just search whether there was any character that is alphanumeric, an underscore, or a hyphen. But really this returns a match only if all the characters fit that description (ie, it fails if there is a space or a dollar sign or asterisk, etc).

I don't really understand how this is working to check all of the characters when it says:

> "The '*', '+', and '?' qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible.".

Doesn't that mean that if there's a space character in at the 6th character it'll match as much as possible and then stop and return the match it found in the first 5 characters (rather than saying "sorry, I found nothing" essentially when it reaches a non-match).

Thanks in advance (I'm such a noob at regex and each time I learn it again I just get confused).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just as per answers above, ^ and $ enclose all charactes in between and they represent line start and end respectively. If in doubt re any expression try debug mode, that usually explains a lot:

```
>>> p = re.compile("^[-\w]+$", re.DEBUG)
at at_beginning
max_repeat 1 65535
  in
    literal 45
    category category_word
at at_end
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

The two characters `^` and `$` mark the start and the end of the string respectively. So `^[-\w]+$` will only match if there are only one or more word characters or a hyphen (`[-\w]+`) between the start (`^`) and the end of the string (`$`).

Comment: So, the ^ start, and $ end characters specify that everything has to match VS [-\w]+ which would match as much as possible, but then stop at a non-match. I think I understand now.

Comment: @orokusaki: To have a match, the following conditions must be fulfilled: 1) **`^`** `[-\w]+$`: there must be a start of the string 2) `^` **`[-\w]+`** `$`: after that, there must be one or more characters that is either a hyphen or a word character 3) `^[-\w]+` **`$`**: after that, there must be the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

The `^` and `$` anchor the regex at the beginning and ending of the string, therefore *all* characters would have to match the pattern in between.

Comment: Actually, only `\A` and `\Z` are guaranteed to mean “match at the start and end of the string”; the `re.MULTILINE` / `(?m)` flag changes the meaning of `^` and `$` to start and end of line, respectively.